# Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am getting the following error:

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in
> components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
> undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file
> it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `Grid`.

My react code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import ReactDataGrid from "react-data-grid";
import { Toolbar, Data } from "react-data-grid-addons";
import axios from 'axios';

const selectors = Data.Selectors;

const columns = [
  { key: "MEMBER", name: "MEMBER", editable: true },
  { key: "ALIAS", name: "ALIAS", editable: true },
  { key: "STATUS", name: "STATUS", editable: true }
];

const handleFilterChange = filter => filters => {
  const newFilters = { ...filters };
  if (filter.filterTerm) {
    newFilters[filter.column.key] = filter;
  } else {
    delete newFilters[filter.column.key];
  }
  return newFilters;
};

function getRows(rows, filters) {
  return selectors.getRows({ rows, filters });
}

async function createRowData() {

  const response = await axios.get('/api/files/fileData/Allupdate.txt');  // returns an array of objects
  console.log(response)
  return response.data;

}

function Example({ rows }) {
  console.log('rows', rows);        // I get this in console.log `rows Promise {<pending>}`

  const [filters, setFilters] = useState({});
  const filteredRows = getRows(rows, filters);
  return (
    <ReactDataGrid
      columns={columns}
      rowGetter={i => filteredRows[i]}
      rowsCount={filteredRows.length}
      minHeight={500}
      toolbar={<Toolbar enableFilter={true} />}
      onAddFilter={filter => setFilters(handleFilterChange(filter))}
      onClearFilters={() => setFilters({})}
    />
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Example rows={createRowData()} />, rootElement);
```

[image]

Comment: What line is causing the error?

Comment: @DrewReese updated a screen shot.

Comment: What details are in those 20 collapsed stack frames? I.E. what does the callstack look like? This could/should provide some hint as to what within your entire `Example` component code had an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your error comes because you're trying to render a function as a component. I mean that Example is not a component, it's a function. So when React tries to render Example, he search for the component.

Is Example a built-in component? -> No

Is Example a composite component? -> No

then throws the Error.

Try this: (I don't know if it will work)

```
ReactDOM.render(Example(createRowData()), rootElement);
```

I mean, try to call the function into the render, not a class that doesn't exist.

Comment: `Example` is a functional component. I'm not sure what you mean by "built-in" or "composite" component.

Comment: nvm. Searching for that error on Google i saw some peopple make it to work changing: `import ReactDataGrid from "react-data-grid";` to `const ReactDataGrid = require('react-data-grid');`